# uv4l usb camera stream not working

Tags: usb, camera, pi-3b+, uv4l, webrtc

I am using a raspberry pi 3b+, trying to make the usb camera work with uv4l streaming.

These are the packages I've installed:

```
uv4l uv4l-raspicam uv4l-raspicam-extras uv4l-server uv4l-uvc uv4l-xscreen uv4l-mjpegstream uv4l-dummy uv4l-raspidisp
```

I've modified the /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf config as `driver=uvc`.

And this is what I got when I run it:

```
uv4l --syslog-host 192.168.1.75 --driver uvc --device-id 1e4e:0109
<notice> [core] Trying to loading driver 'uvc' from built-in drivers...
<notice> [core] Loading driver 'uvc' from external plug-in's...
<notice> [driver] Video functionality 'USB2.0 Camera' recognized at 1e4e:0109
<notice> [core] Device detected!
<warning> [core] Cannot create /dev/uv4l because file already exists
<alert> [core] Device file already exists: File exists generic:17
```

Seems all good, but when I open `192.168.1.75:8090`, although the webpage shows properly, if I click on stream or webrtc, no image shows, if I click "Call" button on webrtc, it alerts `"invalid video device!"`

Then I tried `dd if=/dev/uv4l of=snapshot.jpeg bs=11M count=1`, it stucked for a very long time and copy speed is 0:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dd if=/dev/uv4l of=snapshot.jpeg bs=11M count=1


^C0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 2393.37 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

And BTW, in case these are relevant, I couldn't get the raspberry pi on board camera (the one with a flat cable) working neither, `vcgencmd get_camera` shows `supported=1 detected=0` and the led on the camera is on. Also, there are these many files under `/dev/`

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root video   240,   0 Jul  3 20:13 video0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root video   238,   1 Jul  3 20:48 video1
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video    81,   0 Jul  3 20:13 video10
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video    81,   1 Jul  3 20:13 video11
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video    81,   2 Jul  3 20:13 video12
```

Maybe not very relevant.

Just trying to get the usb camera to work for now, did I miss anything? Thanks